# How to prevent JComboBox from closing?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

After selecting an item from a JComboBox, i want to keep the JComboBox still opened to allow the user to choose another item from it. Is that possible ?

I hope you can provide me an example.

Comment: what are you asking for jComboBox is already designed for selecting and changing selection as required what do you mean by remain open?

Comment: @moon: When a user selects an item from the JComboBox i make a condition check in my code, if the check returned true i want to close the JComboBox list. If the condition check returned false, i want to keep the JComboBox opened so the user can choose another item.

Comment: @moon: I do not have code yet for this. I am in the design phase. If you want to understand what i want to do, you can check a similar Combo box here but written in another language: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps what you are after is a [`JList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) instead.

Comment: @Krock: No .. I have to use a JComboBox. I am not looking for multi selection. I just want to allow the user to choose another item if the first item he chose was wrong. I have to do this to respect my GUI design.

Comment: @Brad, you can do those by using a [`ListSelectionModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) and setting it to `SINGLE_SELECTION`

Comment: @Brad, JComboBox was not built for this, you should use JList.

Comment: @krock: That is not the answer i hoped to hear, but i have googled for some time and couldn't find any clue for this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW I believe @MByD has a good point, don't even give the user the option to choose a value they can't choose.

Answer (score 1):

As a different approach, maybe you can display in the `JComboBox` only the "allowed to choose" items in first place?